# Shrinking or partially truncating a file in DOS/FAT

Tags: c, file-io, dos, truncate, fat

I've been tasked with writing a data collection program for a [Unitech HT630](http://us.ute.com/products_info.php?rbu=5&pc1=48&pc2=72&pid=274), which runs a proprietary DOS operating system that can run executables compiled for 16-bit MS DOS with some restrictions. I'm using the Digital Mars C/C++ compiler, which is working well thus far.

One of the application requirements is that the data file must be human-readable plain text, meaning the file can be imported into Excel or opened by Notepad.  I'm using a variable length record format much like CSV that I've successfully implemented using the C standard library file I/O functions.

When saving a record, I have to calculate whether the updated record is larger or smaller than the version of the record currently in the data file.  If larger, I first shift all records immediately after the current record forward by the size difference calculated before saving the updated record. EOF is extended automatically by the OS to accommodate the extra data.  If smaller, I shift all records backwards by my calculated offset.  This is working well, however I have found no way to modify the EOF marker or file size to ignore the data after the end of the last record.

Most of the time records will grow in size because the data collection program will be filling some of the empty fields with data when saving a record.  Records will only shrink in size when a correction is made on an existing entry, or on a normal record save if the descriptive data in the record is longer than what the program reads in memory.

In the situation of a shrinking record, after the last record in the file I'm left with whatever data was sitting there before the shift.  I have been writing an EOF delimiter into the file after a "shrinking record save" to signal where the end of my records are and space-filling the remaining data, but then I no longer have a clean file until a "growing record save" extends the size of the file over the space-filled area.  The `truncate()` function in `unistd.h` does not work (I'm now thinking this is for *nix flavors only?).

One proposed solution I've seen involves creating a second file and writing all the data you wish to save into *that* file, and then deleting the original.  Since I only have 4MB worth of disk space to use, this works if the file size is less than 2MB minus the size of my program executable and configuration files, but would fail otherwise.  It is very likely that when this goes into production, users would end up with a file exceeding 2MB in size.

I've looked at [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) and the interrupt reference in [IBM PC Assembly Language and Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013030655X) and I can't seem to find anything to update the file size or similar.

Is reducing a file's size without creating a second file even possible in DOS?

Comment: Does the FAT FS live on Flash?  It may not be an issue (depending on use), but defragmentating the file in this way will not play nice with flash's limited erase/write life.

Comment: @nategoose - The unit has a RAM-drive partition and a 256k flash partition, I'm strictly working with the RAM-drive at the moment. The flash partition is only used for storing programs, not data.

Comment: Some operating systems, including DOS, may pad the file to the nearest efficient sector size.  Files starting on an even sector boundary are easier and faster to retrieve than those that aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reduce a file's size in DOS, you seek to the point of truncation with `int 21 (ax=4200h, bx=handle, cx:dx=offset)` and call write with zero length: `int 21 (ax=4000h, bx=handle, cx=0` (meaning truncate))

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to shifting the records around when resizing a record, you could finish each record with a "pad" field that pads it out to a standard size (eg with spaces or similar).